# Powershell: Output for Record not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following small scriptlet:

```powershell
$JSON_obj = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\importfile.json" | ConvertFrom-JSON

foreach ($Record_Set in $JSON_obj) {

 $Record_Set.Records

}
```

Running the script does not show anything on the console. If I manually type Record_Set.Records, the data will be shown. Any idea what could be the issue?

e.g.
$Record_Set.Records-->

```
Host         : ns1-01.azure-dns.com.
Email        : azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com.
SerialNumber : 1
RefreshTime  : 3600
RetryTime    : 300
ExpireTime   : 2419200
MinimumTtl   : 300
```

Comment: can you please provide sample json file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try and add `write-host`:

```
$JSON_obj = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\importfile.json" | ConvertFrom-JSON

foreach ($Record_Set in $JSON_obj) {

 write-host $Record_Set.Records

}
```

Comment: thanks! That worked -I was sure I also tried it before... but anyhow... since it now works, I'm happy ;)

Comment: Happy for you :)